# Getting the right CBOR output

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, cbor

I have a little code snippet, where I try to serialize a map, kind of a JSON object into a CBOR ByteArray. But I can not get the same output as in the CBOR playground cbor.me

The thing I want to serialize to CBOR is this:

```
{
123: [22,67,2] , 
456 : [34,22,1]
}
```

If I serialize this in cbor.me I get:

```
A2          # map(2)
   18 7B    # unsigned(123)
   83       # array(3)
      16    # unsigned(22)
      18 43 # unsigned(67)
      02    # unsigned(2)
   19 01C8  # unsigned(456)
   83       # array(3)
      18 22 # unsigned(34)
      16    # unsigned(22)
      01    # unsigned(1)
```

My code looks like this:

```
val mapper = CBORMapper()
val map = HashMap<Any,Any>()
map[123] = intArrayOf(22,67,2)
map[456] = intArrayOf(34,12,1)
val cborData = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(map)
println(cborData.toHex())
val deserialized = mapper.readValue(cborData, HashMap<Any,Any>().javaClass)
```

The output from the print is this:

```
bf-19-01-c8-83-18-22-0c-01-18-7b-83-16-18-43-02-ff
```

TLDR
How can I get the same output as in the CBOR playground?